# How do I run launch kdiff3 as a background process so it accepts two ClearCase version controlled files as parameters?

Tags: bash, clearcase, kdiff3

How do I run launch kdiff3 as a background process so it accepts two ClearCase version controlled files as parameters?  When run as a background process, kdiff3 claims it does not have permission to read a file, but it has no permission issues with that same file when it is not run as a background process.

The following launches kdiff3, but not as a background process:

```
$ kdiff3 source.c@@/main/branch/30 source.c
```

Here is the command and result of directing kdiff3 to run as a background process:

```
$ kdiff3& source.c@@/main/branch/30 source.c
[4] 31907
bash: source.c@@/main/branch/30: Permission denied
[3]   Done                    kdiff3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
kdiff3 source.c@@/main/branch/30 source.c &
```

Or, just for testing, you can try and wrapp the call in a script:

```
testdiff.sh

kdiff3 source.c@@/main/branch/30 source.c
```

And call the script as a background process:

```
testdiff&
```